# How to set virtualenv to stay active on a host server

Tags: django, virtualenv

I created a website that uses vuejs as the frontend and django as the backend with another service running behind everything that im making api calls to.

So django is setup in a way to look at the dist folder of Vuejs and serve it if you run manage.py runserver. but the problem is that my service that I created is
is also in python and it needs to run in a virtualenv in order to work (It uses tensorflow 1.15.2 and this can only run in a contained environment)

I'm sitting here and wondering how I can deploy the django application and keep the virtualenv active and Im coming up with nothing, I've tried doing some research on this but everything I found was not relevant to my problem. I've deployed it and when I close the ssh connection the virtualenv stops.

If there is anyone that can enlighten my ways I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where have you deployed your application, as in heroku or aws ec2 you don't need venv

Comment: @AchintyaRanjanChaudhary Digital Ocean Centos8 droplet

Comment: runserver should not be used in production, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/

Comment: @iklinac I did not say that I was running runserver in development. I was explaining my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

if you are search for keep states just in terminal i suggest tmux https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Comment: Thank you for your help the documentation gave me a better insight on how to achive my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use uWSGI and nginx to deploy Django apps on server. Here's helpful articles:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-centos-7
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-centos-7

Django official docs also has a page about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/

There are articles from developers so you can refer them in case you get stuck anywhere:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/django-uwsgi-nginx-postgresql-setup-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu16-04-with-python-3-6-6c58698ae9d3/

https://medium.com/@biswashirok/deploying-django-python-3-6-to-digital-ocean-with-uwsgi-nginx-ubuntu-18-04-3f8c2731ade1

Comment: Thank @stuti verma,  the freecodecamp resource and Nima nima's GitHub URL really helped wish I could mark both answers correct.